# How to send three pipes of data over ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a bash script on a remote host that produces a large amount of data on fd=3 as well as some possibly interesting data on stdout and stderr.  I want to:

1. Log stdout and stderr to a file on my local machine.
2. Write the data on fd=3 to stdout on my local machine.

Here's how it could be done if my big script were local:

```
exec 3> >(cat)
./big_script.sh -o /dev/fd/3 2>&1 >big_script.log
exec 3>&-
```

However, I want to run big_script.sh on  a remote machine and have all three pipes (fd=1, fd=2, and fd=3) come out of the ssh program as separate.  What is the best way to that?

Answer (score 2):

nc (netcat) and tunnels ? you can make kinda log radio on your net this way!

Comment: That's a very tempting option.  I have one small problem.  There are actually several processes on my local machine that will call the big_script.sh.  How do I build the tunnels so they never use the same port on the remote machine?

Comment: maybe with netstat -lnpt and grep already taken? that will make a longer script probably with more than one connections  .... not to say you need to manage the concurrency

Answer (score 0):

SSH opens just a single tty, so you just get a single stream that has all the data. You cannot tell apart what went to what the other side seen as stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You could log to files on the remote host, and then `ssh remote tail -f` each of the log files from your local machine.