# How to tar a fifo

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, tar

I want to tar the output of a program that writes to stdout and a fifo at fd=3.  Here was my first attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create fd=3
exec 3> >(cat)

#Start the tar
tar -cvzf ha.tgz /dev/fd/1 /dev/fd/3

#Write data
echo stdout
echo 'fd=3'>&3

#close
exec 3>&-
```

It created ha.tgz and its contents were /dev/fd/1 and /dev/fd/3.  However when I extract the files, it basically creates symlinks to /dev/fd/1 and /dev/fd/3 (which is broken).  I was hoping the files would just be regular files whose content would be what I echo'd in the script.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Server Fault or Superuser: http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: If you don't supply file(s) to tar, only a stream of data, what do you expect to get on the other side when you unter it?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I expect the contents of the stream, not the stream itself.  When the script ends both fd's are closed, so tar should see an EOF and be able to complete the archive.  Of course, I could write to regular files but then I would have to delete them when the tar is complete.  It just does not seem elegant to me.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do this?

No. The entries under /dev are not real files, they are only file-like interfaces to device drivers. If you want regular files, use regular files.

Answer (score 2):

With zip it should work like this:

`zip -FI MyZipFile /dev/fd/1 /dev/fd/3`

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the fifo contents into `gzip` and to a file.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin Cantu. I can't see how it is possible to have multiple streams in a single file. There is no way to untangle them later, so if you end up with a single data object, you don't need the services of tar, and gzip will happily compress its' standard input.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question was clear.  I don't want "streams" in a file.  I want the data that was sent through those streams to be somehow captured in a single file that can be sent on one stream.  Specifically in my case that stream will be ssh.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320132/how-to-send-three-pipes-of-data-over-ssh.

Comment: So you want to send both data streams over the network?  Use something else like `netcat` or whatever for each instead of `gzip`.  Same paradigm.